# How do I stop my chain distorting along a curve?

Tags: modifiers

I am sure this is fairly simple. I followed a simple chain tutorial and as you can see the pieces elongate around the bends for some reason

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You chain seems to be too far away from the deforming curve.

Comment: Can you share the .blend using [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so we can have a look at what's going on?

Comment: I have uploaded the blender file. I am having a lot of problem with all the ropes and chains relationship to their curve modifiers. There is obviously something I am not getting

Answer (score 1):

The origin of both objects (chain and curve) matters for the curve modifier.

To correct the issue:

- Place the 3D cursor on the first vertex of the curve, then come back in object mode and transform the curve origin to the 3D cursor.
- And move the chain to that origin (considering the chain origin is ok, relatively to the chain itself)

[image]

Some information or tips:

Here we start with a simple position where all objects are oriented along the X axis and the curve modifier is set along X too (the modifier's result is not shown below).

[image]

Now we activate the modifier and grab the chain's origin near the curve origin:

[image]

We notice that:

- The more the chain is near the curve, the less it is stretched
- When both origins are at the same location, the chain begins at the first curve's control point

If we rotate, move, or change the chain in edit mode:

[image]

If we rotate, move, or change the chain in edit mode:

[image]

And if we change the chain's control points:

[image]

So aligning the chain and the curve:

- Set both origins at the same location
- Set the modifier's axis along the chain axis
- The chain will be curved starting at the first control point of the curve and starting from its own origin (and the result depends on the position of its inner geometry relative to its origin)

Comment: it is following the right lines but the chain is bigger than the curve, and when I move it, it all goes out of shape again. What am I missing?

Comment: Depending on the way you are modifying the curve, you may need to do the same again (as in the answer) or modify the array count: the point is to start both objects at the same point (curve origin=curve first control point and object origin). Also move them together if you move at object level.

Comment: I have added a picture of what I have ended up with

Comment: This is the same principle: as I said, to solve it here, make so that the three locations which are "curve origin" "curve first control point" and "chain object" (considering the chain origin is nearly at the center of the first link) are the same.

Comment: @DaveGoateze, FYI, I have retry to understand how you could have a bad result (like in your second image)... and the only way I see can be: moving or rotating the chain or the curve separately ; make so that objects origins are not at the same position ; move the chain in edit mode so that its origin is no more near its center of geometry.

Comment: thanks a lot mate. I tried it once and it disappeared, then I did Shift + Ctrl + Alt + C geometry to origin and it finally followed the curve.