# Why is my chain (array, curve) distorting on my subdivided curve in Blender 2.8?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

On Blender 2.8 & I followed this as well as other to no avail: [How do I stop my chain distorting along a curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74532/how-do-i-stop-my-chain-distorting-along-a-curve)

My origins seem to be where they should be. Chain at first seems okay. Then I subdivide the curve, move vertices where I want, and what results is a bad distortion. [image]

Tried re-doing the origin stuff in tutorials after I do the subdividing/vertex moving, no dice. The curve has no rotation to clear. I'm out of ideas.

What do I do?